# Заполнить input по клику

Tags: javascript

```
 <input id="input">
 <ul id="ul">
      <li>Текст 1</li>
      <li>Текст 2</li>
      <li>Текст 3</li>
 </ul>
```

Как имея примерно такую структуру заполнять `input` текстом из `li` по клику?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Html:
Не надо назначать элементам айдишники такие же как названия существующих тегов. Иначе Вы очень быстро начнете путаться в трех елках.

```
 <input id="myInput">
 <ul id="myList">
      <li>Текст 1</li>
      <li>Текст 2</li>
      <li>Текст 3</li>
 </ul>
```

Javascript:
Не надо вешать обработчики на каждый элемент списка. Вешаем обработчик на сам список, а потом ловим event.target. Это называется [делегирование событий](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation), и применяется чтобы не плодить множество одинаковых обработчиков.

```
var myList = document.getElementById('myList'),
    myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');

myList.addEventListener('click', function(event){
   myInput.value = event.target.innerHTML;
});
```

Comment: Круто, не знал о таком.

Comment: Вот только у меня ошибку кидает ваш код (script.js:74 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null)

Comment: @МатвейМамонов, обратите внимание, я html тоже поменял

Comment: А, да, не заметил сразу. А как это работает? Мы ловим клик по ul, а потом как оно работает?

Comment: @идентикон не спорю. Век живи - век учись, что называется.

Comment: @МатвейМамонов, просто как топор. Да так же как и ваше. Просто берем внутренности элемента по которому кликнули. Разница лишь в том, что у нас висит один обработчик, а не множество.
https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation

Comment: @МатвейМамонов Спасибо

Comment: @ru_volt самое обидное то, что w3school этих знаний не дает. Упустил я это. Спасибо за ссылку ;) Удачи

Comment: @ru_volt кстати, а event.target на какой уровень вложенности действует? Ваш пример будет работать, если будут вложенные li?

Comment: @smellyshovel  https://jsfiddle.net/209r7vLw/1/
Для клика event.target - это непосредственно сама нода, на которой кликнули. Самая глубокая.

Comment: @ru_volt все, теперь вопросов не осталось, благодарю.

Comment: А почему при выделении в инпут заносится html разметка? https://jsfiddle.net/nuwnn7f0/

Comment: @идентикон, потому что есть строчка, которая недвусмысленно говорит это сделать: event.target.innerHTML. Если разметка не нужна, нужно содержимое дочерних нод только, то попробуйте event.target.innerText. Если разметка сложная, то не надо бездумно делегировать, я накидал для вашего простого примера из вопроса

Comment: @ru_volt Нет, разметка нужна, это же логично

Answer (score 2):

```
let lis = document.querySelectorAll("li");
for (let i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    lis[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        replaceToInput(lis[i]);
    });
}

function replaceToInput(elem) {
    input = document.getElementById("input");
    input.setAttribute("value", elem.innerHTML);
}
```

Протестировал у себя, теперь код работает.

Comment: это Вы получается должны создать input id="input" я верно понял ?

Comment: Я тоже сейчас попробую

Comment: @LenovoID Или поменять на свой id

Comment: идентикон , а разве нельзя обратится к инпут без идентификатора ?

Comment: @LenovoID он уже есть у ТС.

Comment: Он выложил код, в котором явно указано, что input имеет id="input", поэтому и решение такое.

Comment: Матвей ссори , моя не внимательность

Comment: Можно передавать ближайшему инпуту, но это уже сложнее.

Comment: а как через js обращаться к селектору по nth-child ?

Comment: @LenovoID А зачем обращаться ко всем инпутам?

Comment: @LenovoID `querySelectorAll` принимает css путь, так что там можно указать nth-child (только я не понял, зачем)

Comment: Код работает? Мое решение подошло? Тогда помечайте его как правильное.

Comment: а ну да , спасибо , затупил я

Comment: @LenovoID ничего, бывает :D